# Making an OAuth request with Laravel for Stripe

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I was translating following PHP code:

```php
$person = \Stripe\Account::createPerson(
    '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}', // id of the account created earlier
    [
       'person_token' => $token,
    ]);
```

To:

```php
$making_user = $stripe->account()->persons()->create(
    $request[0], // id of the account created earlier
    [
       'person_token' => $request[1],
    ]);
```

Above Laravel code works find without any issue. Does anyone have any idea that what can be the equivalent Laravel syntax of the following:

```php
$response = \Stripe\OAuth::token([
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => 'ac_123456789',
]);
```

I'm using following as equivalent, but it is giving me error of invalid method "oauth"

```php
$making_account = $stripe->oauth()->create([
        'grant_type' => $request['code'],
        'code' => 'ac_123456789',
    ]);
```

I'm not finding anywhere its syntax anyone have an idea what will be the Laravel syntax of making `Oauth` call?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even know Lavarel supported the Connect APIs like Person Create, I thought it was just Cashier for the Subscriptions APIs. Maybe they just don't support the OAuth routes? Internally they are very different routes(connect.stripe.com/oauth instead of api.stripe.com/v1) so maybe it's just not something built into Lavarel today. Do you have the Lavarel docs for what you're following?

Comment: @emotality yes, but there is nothing relate do ouath in laravel documentation

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker tagged the wrong person, I'm not part of the discussion I just edited the question :)

Comment: Sorry, @emotality my bad. :) BTW I got an answer to this.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker then you should answer your own question and mark it as correct for the next person :P

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('SECRET_KEY_HERE');
$response = $stripe->oauth->token([
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => 'CODE_HERE'
]);
```